# Manipulating data from excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I was given the task to manipulate the data from an excel sheet with python to show an interactive activity sequence network diagram using networkx, panda and matplotlib.

The network diagram but me interactive
Every change of direction of arrow towards generated nodes but be reflected on the excel sheet
The generated network diagram should be able to show shortest routes for every node when interacted with
Every node should be assigned a different code. a node with no predecessor, a node with one predecessor, a node with two predecessors etc.
An arrow showing the direction of master

how can i write the script to produce a real time sheet and network diagram at the same time.

```
import xlrd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import panda as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#converting excel data to a dictionary

path = "path_to_my_excel_sheet"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path, on_demand = True)
workbook = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

headers = []
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
headers.append(worksheet.cell_value(0. col))

for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
  elm = {}
  for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
  elm[headers[cols]] = worksheet.cell_value(row, col)
  return elm

#creating a panda data frame

df = pd.DataFrame(elm)
carc = pd.DataFrame(elm['Task_ID'], got stuck on how to proceed)
```

Comment: Not necessarily answering your question, but pandas can read excel directly into a Dataframe instead of reading the workbook line by line...[See here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

So you can actually load an excel sheet into Pandas using the read_excel() method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('OPT.xlsx')
```

And Once your finished with your dataframe, you can actually use Pandas excel writer to write your files sheets out:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("sampleFile.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet1') #or whatever sheetname you want here
```

Comment: Not really what am looking for. Am trying to read an excel file, automatically get the headers, and the rest of the data underneath that. Then pass this datas to panda to create a network activity plot with networkx

Comment: So pandas has the has headers alongside their column values.   Are you saying you need help with networkx portion?

Comment: i think i will need such aid. will it be possible to reflect alteration done on the generated network plot to be reflected on the excel data automatically? (move arrow from node 7 to node 3)

Comment: am try to merge all this code into a PyQt5 GUI that i have created and wondering how to wrap it all up as one program

Comment: here is my email (michaelkalango@gmail.com) so we can have a good follow up on the project. Its an assignment and am to submit next week. Its really killing to handle all the bugs am having.
GitHub link (https://github.com/moak13/Linknoide) for the project, would love to add you up as a contributor to help speed things up.

Comment: So to wrap it into one program you can use pyinstaller.  Its really easy.  Check out their site:  https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: I'm grateful for the email, I'll check out the github code as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks, i am really grateful. i know of the pyinstaller, what am talking about is how to make the two views function as one. when the excel shit is picked from the first view, its then passed to the next view for manipulation and others.